# mysqli to pdo simple select statement

Tags: mysql, pdo

I just converted some MySQL to mysqli, but realized I do not have access to the mysqlnd driver with my server setup.  So, I need to now convert to PDO which I have available.

I am trying to convert the following to PDO, but there is no bind_result available in PDO from what I have read.  I need to use a prepared statement for this as there is user input.

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user,pass FROM test_users WHERE user = ?");
    // bind params
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    // execute prepared statement
    $stmt->execute();
    // Bind result variables
    $stmt->bind_result($ruser, $rpass); 
    // fetch values
    $stmt->fetch();     
    // close statement
    $stmt->close();
```

Can anyone help out quick?  Here is what I have, but not sure how to retrieve the resulting values into useable variables...

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user,pass FROM test_users WHERE user = ?");
    // bind params
    $value = $_POST['username'];
    // execute prepared statement
    $stmt->execute($value);
    // stmt now holds results, but how can I retrieve them into useable values?
    // ?    
    // close statement
    $stmt->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make yourself familiar with arrays. They are no less "useable" than regular variables.
And sometimes arrays even more usable, especially in your case.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user, pass FROM test_users WHERE user = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Now $row contains the row returned by query. Now you can test if any data returned and then use it.

For the password check you can use it this way

```
if ($row && $row['pass'] === whatever_hash_used($_POST['password']]))
{
    unset($row['pass']);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Your statement is pretty much what I just wrote down before looking although I didn't put the post directly into the execute.  Why did you not use $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);?

Comment: Also why are the double brackets required - $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);

Answer (score 1):

You can return values from a PDO query with the [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method. There are various ways of fetching the data, such as into an array, into an object, and into a lazy-loading object. The simplest of these, and the most appropriate in your circumstance, is an array. In this case, you need to use the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` constant.

```
 $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can then access `$results['user']` and `$results['pass']`.

A nice way of improving this would be to fetch `$user` and `$pass` variables rather than an array. This can be done with the [`list`](https://www.php.net/list) construct:

```
list($user, $pass) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

---

The other problem with your code (as Your Common Sense may or may not be pointing out in the comments: it's a little hard to tell) is that your code to bind the variables isn't quite right. `PDOStatement::execute` expects an array:

```
$stmt->execute(array($value));
$stmt->execute([$value]); // from PHP 5.4
```

In my opinion, the nicer way to do this is with named parameters:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT user, pass FROM test_users WHERE user = :user');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();

list($user, $pass) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: That wasn't me with the downvote... list seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  Just like you said, I just want the variables rather than the array although in this particular case either would work.  Is one faster than the other?

Comment: @user756659 There will be no discernable difference.

Comment: appreciate it... so basically every time I want to retrieve any values from the statement I will always be using fetch or fetchAll... one result or all results.  Thanks this cleared things up. I did not know about list either from what I have read so far.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh, I see what you mean. I'm quite sure you don't need to be so obnoxious, however.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Do you want to explain, or do you want to make sarcastic comments all day?

Comment: @user756659 It works fine, though you should pay attention to the edit I've just made.

Comment: Shouldn't that be list($user, $pass) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?

Comment: @user756659 No, because `list` wants numbered keys.